Comment/Uncomment Selection Missing
I am upgrading my laptop and have downloaded/installed Visual Studio 2022.  When I click on Edit/Advanced the options Comment Selection and Uncomment Selection are missing.
I have searched and attempted to use Tools/Customize, but have been unable to find how to add those options.
Does anybody know how to add those back into Visual Studio?
Thanks

What kind of file do you have open and focused when you try this? (whats the extension)

It was happening with code files.  Meaning either a .razor or a .cs file.
And, incidentally, all is still working great -- I don't know how to break it again???

Right click on any free space in the Visual Studio toolbar, then select “Text Editor”.
and you will see the comment and uncomment section button.
Shortcuts ctrl+KC/KU will work also.

Thank you amadeusz.  I have no explanation, but the comment/uncomment have appeared where expected.  Odd because I have used these for years and never had a problem until the last few days when I moved to a new PC, and then had this issue for several days - meaning that user error seems unlikely.  All good now???
I will hold on to this in case it re-appears.

I think this only controls showing the comment/uncomment buttons in the toolbar but not the Edit → Advanced drop down menu as the OP was asking about.
